# How to make an ODBC connection with Laravel6?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, odbc, driver, laravel-6

I want to connect to SQL Server using ODBC, but I can't find a driver or library that supports Laravel6.

How can I make an ODBC connection with Laravel6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel does not ship with an ODBC driver. For that, you have to find a package that provides that driver and install it via `composer`

One helpful package could be https://github.com/techscope/laravel-sqlserver

Also, as that page mentions, make sure your PHP has the appropriate drivers installed

Comment: Thank you
However, I have PHP version was not supported

Comment: what do you mean? what version do you have?

Comment: My PHP is 7.3.10 and is not supported.

Comment: the sql driver should be available for php7.3. is your code running on linux or windows? because the package i gave you has instructions on how to download the driver for linux and mac but there are drivers for windows too!

Comment: Thank you very much
I try a lot

Comment: Here's the drivers for windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add in Rahul's answer, we can use composer packages for ODBC. an [here's](https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc) one of packages that works fine with Laravel 5+ BUT it may not work with Laravel 6 so for Laravel 6 [here's new one](https://packagist.org/packages/kkszymanowski/laravel-6-odbc)